# How do I add a class with jQuery to a separate DIV only when a table ROW has a certain class?

Tags: jquery, datatables, css-selectors

I am trying to add the **open** class to another DIV outside the table, only IF the table row has a **selected** class.

```
<table id="#resultsTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="selected">
      <td>Follow the white rabbit...</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div class="profile open"></div>
```

This doesn't work...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
if ($("#resultsTable tbody tr").hasClass("selected")) {
    $(".profile").addClass("open");
}});
```

Nor this...

```
$('table tbody tr.selected').closest('.profile').addClass('open');
```

What am I doing wrong? TIA

Comment: `id="#resultsTable"` is not correct. use `id="resultsTable"` . Also html attributes should not be camelCase but divided by `-`. so `results-table` would be better. camelCase should be used when declaring variables in javaScript for eg.

Answer (score 1):

The `id` value in HTML should be `resultsTable` instead of `#resultsTable`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($("#resultsTable tbody tr").hasClass("selected")) {
    $(".profile").addClass("open");
  }
});
```

```css
.open{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="resultsTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="selected">
      <td>Follow the white rabbit...</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div class="profile">div content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first solution doesn't work because `<table id="#resultsTable">` should be `<table id="resultsTable">`. Notice `#` in `id` attribute of the table.

Your second solution doesn't work because
 `closest()` searches **from the element itself to its ancestors in the DOM tree**. But`tr.selected` doesn't have any ancestor with class `profile`.

Comment: Thanks for the response Elish! Is there a JS selector that would find tr.selected?